# How to find words in a list that starts with a certain letter the user asked for

Tags: python, list, letter

so i'm trying to make a program that adds, removes, search, saves and loads a list

i have managed to make everything work apart from searching through the list for the first letters

the program will ask what letter the user wants to search for
It will then search through the list for the first letter the user inputted

All i have managed to do is:

```
mylist = ["hello","world","how","you","doing"]
for word in mylist:
  print (word[0])
```

which does print out the first letters of each word

```
h
w
h
y
d
>>>
```

but what i want to do

```
mylist = ["hello","world","how","you","doing"]
letter = input("input a letter you would like to search ").lower()
```

the letter the user has inputted is to be searched throughout the list

after finding all the words that start with the letter,
i would like it to print out how many words it has found and then print out the words that was found with the letter the user has requested

Answer (score 3):

use list comprehension with `startswith`

```
[i for i in mylist if i.startswith(letter)]
```

It is similar to what you are doing but you are not checking the condition like below

```
mylist = ["hello","world","how","you","doing"]
for word in mylist:
      if word[0]==letter:
            print(word)
```

To play safe use `.lower()` on strings present in list as well

```
mylist = ["Hello","world","how","you","doing"]
letter = 'h'
[i for i in mylist if i.lower().startswith(letter)] #["Hello","how"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for word in list:
    if input() in word:
        print(word)
```

Something on that line. It grabs the word from the list then tests the user input against that word.

Answer (score 0):

You can use List Comprehensions:

```
mylist = ["hello","world","how","you","doing"]
letter = input("input a letter you would like to search ").lower()
result = [word for word in mylist if word.lower().startswith(letter)]
print(len(result))
print(result)
```

You can learn more about the power of [List Comprehensions in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

EDIT (inspired by other answers):
Using `word.startswith()` instead of indexing `word[0]` avoids problems with empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = ["hello","world","how","you","doing"]
letter = input("input a letter you would like to search ").lower()
    input a letter you would like to search 'h'

list_starting_with_letter = [i for i in mylist if i[0].lower()==letter.lower()]
list_starting_with_letter
    ['hello', 'how']

print('Number of such words: '+ str(len(list_starting_with_letter)))
    Number of such words: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/U6ZM2l

```
mylist = ["hello","world","how","you","doing"]
letter = input("input a letter you would like to search ").lower()

words = list(filter(lambda s: s.startswith(letter), mylist))

print( len(words) )

for w in words: print ("\n"+w)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
mylist = ["hello","world","how","you","doing"]
letter = input("input a letter you would like to search ").lower()
found = [] #Result will Store
for m in mylist:
    if m.startswith(letter): #It will check if the input value match with from begining of the signl world
        found.append(m) # Store the value if match
print("Total Words is "+str((len(found))))
for f in found:
    print("Word List :\n"+f)
```

Comment: can easily optimize by not printing the words again in a separate loop